# How to call cross domain wcf in Jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, wcf

I am not able to call wcf service in remote.  I have wcf service in different domain.

Here is the code:

WCF Function:

```
public Customer GetStringName()
{
    return new Customer() { Name = "Pranay", Address = "1 Ahmedabad" };

}
```

Client Call:

```
             $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: "http://124.301.114.83/WCFServicevana/Service.svc/getstringName",
                contentType: "application/json", 
                DataType: 'jsonp',
                ProcessData: false,
                data: "",

                success: function (result) {
                    resultObject = result.getdata;
                    var string = result.Name + " : " + result.Address;
                    alert(string);                   
                },
                error: function (textStatus) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            });
        })
    });
```

crossdomain.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
 <cross-domain-policy>
       <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
 </cross-domain-policy>
```

clientaccesspolicy.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
       <policy>
              <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
               <domain uri="*"/>
              </allow-from>
              <grant-to>
                 <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
                 </grant-to>
         </policy>
      </cross-domain-access>
  </access-policy>
```

I wrote the above coding...  But i didnot get result.   I got empty result.

Any one assist me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the status returned by server?

Comment: `DataType: 'jsonp',` here `d` is uppercase in your `DataType` change to `dataType:'jsonp',`

Comment: put this in success function `console.log(result);` and place in your post the output of it.

Comment: undefined values.... Same coding is working in local.  But not in another domain...